# Passing parameters with #selector

Tags: swift, parameter-passing, notificationcenter

I'm a beginner to Swift and I'm trying to initiate a function through NotificationCenter. The observer  in 'ViewController.swift' calls on function `reload`:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(reload), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "reload"), object: nil)
}

func reload(target: Item) {
    print(target.name)
    print(target.iconName)
}
```

... which has a parameter of class `Ítem`:

```
class Item: NSObject {
    let name: String
    let iconName: String
    init(name: String, iconName: String) {
        self.name = name
        self.iconName = iconName
    }
}
```

The notification is posted from "menu.swift":

```
class menu: UIView, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

let items: [Item] = {
    return [Item(name: "Johnny", iconName: "A"), Item(name: "Alexis", iconName: "B"), Item(name: "Steven", iconName: "C")]
}()

...

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath:
    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "reload"), object: items[indexPath.row])
    }
```

How do I assign the value of object `items[indexPath.row]` from 'menu.swift' to the parameter of function `reload` in 'ViewController.swift'?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to pass an object around classes that are registered to `NotificationCenter`, you should put that into [`.userInfo`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsnotification/1409222-userinfo) dictionary of notification object that is passed to observer function:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(reload), name: Notification(name: "reload"), object: nil)
```

--

```
let userInfo = ["item": items[indexPath.row]]
NotificationCenter.default.post(name: "reload", object: nil, userInfo: userInfo)
```

--

```
func reload(_ notification: Notification) {
  if let target = notification.userInfo?["item"] as? Item {
    print(target.name)
    print(target.iconName)
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That is the correct answer! The observer does not seem to accept `reload(_:)` as a valid #selector argument, but using `#selector(reload)` works just fine instead.