# How to change cell label from another class (View Controller)?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, uicollectionview

So I'm trying to change the likes label that's **in the collection view cell class** from **the collection view controller**. I tried to do it with protocol and delegates and notification center, but my app crashes with lldb when I try to configure the likes label from my View Controller. 
Here's the relevant code:

```
class HomeController: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, HomePostCellDelegate {


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(refreshLikeButtonLabel(for:)), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "refresh"), object: nil)
    }

    @objc func refreshLikeButtonLabel(for cell: HomePostCell) {
        cell.likesLabel.text = "4"
        print("is it working?")

    }
}
```

Cell Class:

```
protocol HomePostCellDelegate {
func refreshLikeButtonLabel(for cell: HomePostCell)
}

class HomePostCell: UICollectionViewCell {

lazy var likesLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.font = UIFont(name: "AvenirNext-Regular", size: 20)
        label.textColor = UIColor.black
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "refresh"), object: nil)
        return label
    }()

override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
}

 required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

Here's what the console says:

```
2017-11-09 07:06:09.969144-0500 Vlogr[1200:24674] [Fabric] unable to complete application configure: Error Domain=FABNetworkError Code=-5 "(null)" UserInfo={status_code=422, type=2, request_id=84d6b91378f57956e1ae930e41915b46, content_type=text/html; charset=utf-8}
(lldb)
```

Let me know if you have any further questions, Thank you!

Comment: No one sends the parameter to the selector! Can you post the crash log?

Comment: Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43056425/2830676

Comment: @Yitzchak I have added the crash log!

Comment: You should send the parameter to the function, and the function needs to be updated to take the label from the parameter, the the link I added above

Comment: @Yitzchak Okay, so I don't need to use protocol and delegates right?

Comment: Correct you don't need

Comment: I don't understand your question

Comment: Did it worked? Don't forget to update us so others will have benefit from your question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158646/discussion-between-erik-batista-and-yitzchak).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the function in view controller like this:

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(reload(_:)), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "refresh"), object: nil)    
}
@objc func reload(_ notification: Notification) {
    if let likesLabel = notification.userInfo?["likesLabelInfo"] as? UILabel {
       likesLabel.text = "4"
    }
}
```

Define the label in the collection view cell here:

```
 lazy var likesLabel: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.font = UIFont(name: "AvenirNext-Regular", size: 20)
    label.textColor = UIColor.black
    let userInfo = ["likesLabelInfo": label]
    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "refresh"), object: nil, userInfo: userInfo)
    return label
}()
```